# antlr4 - get left and right sibling of rule context

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

An easy question, on which I cannot find something useful in the API docs: is there a way to get the left and right sibling of a `ParserRuleContext`?

Say I have in my `.g4`:

```
identifiers : identifier (',' identifier)*;
```

When handling a `IdentifierContext`, I would like to get a reference to the left and the right `IdentifierContext`.

Comment: There can be multiple children so you need to use getChild(int i) method to get the one you want.

Comment: That's not really the question. In my case, I am already `in a child`. I am trying to get to the sibling, not to the `i-th` child.

Comment: You can always `getParent()` and then `getChild(int i)` in the parent node to reach all the siblings.

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to know the index of the current child context, so we can `+  1` and `- 1` that?

Comment: Ah, I get what you are asking now. You can do a `getRuleIndex()` to get the index and then do `+1` and `-1` in the `parent.getChild()` for the siblings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [...] is there a way to get the left and right sibling of a `ParserRuleContext`?

No, alas, there is no direct way to do so in the core API of ANTLR4.

You  could go with infomehdi's answer, but will have to guard against index-oUt-of-bound exceptions when (trying to) retrieve the left- or right node.

Comment: Just not true.  See infomehdi's answer.

Comment: @dsz  sure, there are ways to get them, but I interpreted it as a direct method to  get the left  or right node. Which there isn't. Infomehdi answer will still need manual code to make sure you don't get an exception.

Answer (score 4):

I've found a relevant `getRightSibling()` method [here](https://github.com/sleekbyte/tailor/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sleekbyte/tailor/utils/ParseTreeUtil.java).

Here is my C# port:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the right sibling of the parse tree node.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">A node.</param>
    /// <returns>Right sibling of a node, or null if no sibling is found.</returns>
    public static IParseTree GetRightSibling(this ParserRuleContext context)
    {
        int index = GetNodeIndex(context);

        return index >= 0 && index < context.Parent.ChildCount - 1 
            ? context.Parent.GetChild(index + 1) 
            : null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the node's index with in its parent's children array.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">A child node.</param>
    /// <returns>Node's index or -1 if node is null or doesn't have a parent.</returns>
    public static int GetNodeIndex(this ParserRuleContext context)
    {
        RuleContext parent = context?.Parent;

        if (parent == null)
            return -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < parent.ChildCount; i++)
        {
            if (parent.GetChild(i) == context)
                return i;
        }

        return -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the index of the current child node:

```
int indexOfCurrentChildNode = ctx.getParent().children.indexOf(ctx);
```

Then you can get its right/left sibling by:

```
ctx.parent.getChild(indexOfCurrentChildNode +/- 1)
```